# hibernate mapping resource not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a MappingNotFoundException: resource: TradFileRecord.hbm.xml not found

and this in a core configuratioon

This file like hibernate.cfg.xml file ares located in src/main/resources

the content of hibernate file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      org.postgresql.Driver
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Subtitlor
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      postgres
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      1234
   </property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

      <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="TradFileRecord.hbm.xml"/>

        <!-- cache settings -->
        <class-cache class="com.subtitlor.bean.TradFileRecord" usage="read-write"/>


<!-- <mapping resource="src/main/resources/TradFileRecord.hbm.xml"/> -->
<!-- <mapping class="com/subtitlor/bean/TradFileRecord"/> -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the content of mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.subtitlor.bean.TradFileRecord" table="tradfilerecord">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the TradFileRecord detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="idLigne" type="int" column="idline">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="timeValues" column="timevalues" type="string"/>
      <property name="originalLine1" column="text1" type="string"/>
      <property name="originalLine2" column="text2" type="int"/>
      <property name="TranslatedLine1" column="translatedtext1" type="string"/>
      <property name="TranslatedLine2" column="translatedtext2" type="string"/>
      <property name="fileName" column="filename" type="string"/>
      <property name="descriptionFile" column="descriptionfile" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and a annotations configuration I have another error :could not load Annotations

Could you help me please

I forgot my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency> -->
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that Maven knows that it's a resource, so put it in the src/main/resources directory and then Maven knows to copy it into position, and then it'll be a resource.

Other than building a sources jar, Maven is going to use src/main/java to build from but is not going to copy the source to the target directory, and hence it's not in the completed jar.

Personally, I'd put the mapping file in the same package as the class, so src/main/resources/com/subtitlor/bean/TradFileRecord.hbm.xml.

Comment: these 2 configuration files are in src/main/resources that is the default resources folder for maven projects.  And put a mapping resource file in a class folder seems to be not a best practices, I am going to try